# Is there a cloud dataprep api?

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

Ideally, I would like to write a function to start a dataprep job on one of the following events
kafka message
file added or change to GCS.

I'm thinking I could write the triggers in python if there is a support library. But I can't find one. Happy to use a different language if I don't have python available.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a library available now that you can use.

https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/API-Workflow---Run-Job_145281449

This explains about Dataprep API and how we can run and schedule the jobs.

If you are able to do it using python and this API. Please post example here as well.

Answer (score 0):

The API documentation for the Trifacta related product is available at https://api.trifacta.com.

Note that to use the Google Dataprep API, you will need to obtain an access token (see https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Manage-API-Access-Tokens_145281444).

You must be a project owner to create access tokens and the Dataprep API for that project. Once that's done, you can create access tokens using the Access tokens page, under the user preferences.